# Just Appended Model! Only One Animation Works Now

Tags: animation, append

I've been getting an error when trying to export my blend file from Blender to Unity and someone recommended I try appending everything in my model to a new file. So I tried that. I was able to append ONE of my animations in. I have three.

Now when I go back to the original file, I can only play one animation which is walking. Even if I select my other animations it will only walk forward. The other two are Turn_Left and Turn_Right.

Can anyone tell me why I can't use my other animations now?

Blend File:
[image]

Comment: I couldn't open your file (It's 0 Kb).

Comment: Sorry, can you try one more time? It worked for me.